# Proof of $\frac{\partial {det(\mathbf X)}}{\partial \mathbf X}=det(\mathbf X)(\mathbf X^{-1})^*$

Tags: matrices, derivatives

let X be a square, complex, and Hermitian matrix. Show that

$\frac{\partial {det(\mathbf X)}}{\partial \mathbf X}=det(\mathbf X)(\mathbf X^{-1})^*$ and $\frac{\partial {det(\mathbf X)}}{\partial \mathbf X^*}=det(\mathbf X)(\mathbf X^{-1})$

Can anyone teach me how to prove this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $X$ is invertible, we have

$$\det(X + \epsilon) = \det(X(1 + X^{-1} \epsilon)) = \det(X) \det(1 + X^{-1} \epsilon) = \det(X) (1 + \text{tr}(X^{-1} \epsilon)).$$

Here $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal matrix. The derivative of $\det X$, as a function from $n \times n$ matrices to scalars, is a linear functional from $n \times n$ matrices to scalars, and these can be identified with $n \times n$ matrices using the [Hilbert-Schmidt inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) $\text{tr}(X^{\ast} Y)$; that is, the linear functional $Y \mapsto \text{tr}(X^{\ast} Y)$ gets identified with $X$. With respect to this identification, the above computation shows that the derivative of $\det(X)$ at $X$ is the linear functional

$$\epsilon \mapsto \det(X) \text{tr}(X^{-1} \epsilon)$$

and hence it gets identified with the matrix $\det(X) (X^{-1})^{\ast}$ as desired. There is no need to assume that $X$ is Hermitian.

The same trick of using an infinitesimal matrix can be used to differentiate basically any matrix function. It can be made fully rigorous in several ways, and I have no idea why nobody seems to teach it.

Comment: What does " ↦" mean? why is det$(1+X^{-1}\epsilon)=(1+tr(X^{-1}\epsilon))$Why does that det become trace?

Comment: @electronic component: $\mapsto$ is read "mapsto"; it's a way of specifying a function without naming it, but instead specifying how it transforms inputs into outputs. For example an alternative way of describing the squaring function $f(x) = x^2$ is $x \mapsto x^2$. It's a general fact that the coefficients of $\det (1 + At)$ , as a polynomial in $t$ (which here is a scalar), are the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (up to sign and ordering); in particular the linear term is $t \text{tr}(A)$.

Comment: You can verify for yourself, directly from the standard expansion of the determinant, that computing $\det (1 + A)$ produces $1 + \text{tr}(A)$ plus terms of quadratic order in $A$, which become negligible as the coefficients of $A$ become small; symbolically we have $\det (1 + A) = 1 + \text{tr}(A) + O(|A|^2)$ which says precisely that the derivative of $\det$ at the identity is $\text{tr}$, as a linear functional.

Comment: Does the infinitesimal matrix mean that elements in the matrix are very tiny,so $ A+ϵ  \approx A?$ ,$ϵ $can be transform to $det(X)tr(X^{−1}ϵ)$ ,but why does $det(X)tr(X^{−1}ϵ)$ can become $det(X)(X{−1})^∗$,not just  $det(X)(X{−1})$ ? and why does infinitesimal matrix can be seem as  $\frac{∂det(X)}{∂X}$? Sorry for asking so many other question